# Subtract 1 from all values in dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a dictionary like the following:

```
dict = {'hi':1, 'hi2':2, 'lskdjf':3}
```

It continues like this for over a million values.

I want to convert this into a dictionary with a value starting at 0

For example, this is the desired output:

```
dict = {'hi':0, 'hi2':1, 'lskdjf':2}
```

How can this be done efficiently?

Comment: `{k: v-1 for k, v in my_dict.items()}` ?

Comment: Is updating the code that generates the dict in the first place an option?

Comment: Or can you just minus 1 when using the dictionary later?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can either iterate over the dictionary to update it...

```
for k in dict_:
    dict_[k] -= 1
```

... or create a new dictionary with a dictionary comprehension.

```
new_dict = {k: v - 1 for k, v in dict_.items()}
```

In both cases note that I replaced your variable name by `dict_` to avoid overwriting the built-in `dict` name.

Comment: It's more efficient (and possibly clearer) to iterate dictionary items, i.e. `for k, v in dict_items: dict_[k] = v-1`.